# Private Pod Architecture Not Found When Including Realm Frameworks

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, cocoapods, podspec

I'm using CocoaPods developing a project in pieces of private pods. 
I got a problem with including Realm frameworks into my private pod:

> ld: framework not found Realm for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

(This error happened when trying to include Realm frameworks in a podspec file)
I filed an issue(github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5230) at Realm.
Yet, the problem remained unsolved.
You don't have to go over that issue, I copied most of it to this post.
So I want to ask you guys and see if there's any clue to solve this problem.

## Report

### What did you do?

Let's assume the sample project's name is `RealmTest`.
I created it by using `pod lib create RealmTest`.
And I added the two necessary frameworks, for Realm to run in Swift, into the directory `RealmTest` within the root project directory.
I added the line `s.vendored_frameworks = 'RealmTest/Realm.framework', 'RealmTest/RealmSwift.framework'` to the podspec file.
And then I did a `pod install` for the Example project.

### What did you expect to happen?

The build did succeed and I expect by doing all those to speed up the build time of the project, instead of compiling Realm from source code.

### What happened instead?

Until I `import RealmSwift` and started to use it.
The build report says as mentioned earlier:

`ld: framework not found Realm for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

#### Notes

1. I specifically use `lipo -info` to check both of the Realm's frameworks, downloaded from their official site. Both of them support all of the four architectures.
2. Both of the frameworks are already included into the `Pods`.
3. And in the project's product directory(the compile technically succeeded, but the link failed at the end), both frameworks are indeed included in the app bundle's framework directory.

### Experiment

I created a dummy framework which supports all of the architectures and added it to the project.
With Realm import commented out, the project gets built successfully.
Once I import Realm module, the error resurfaces!
But one of the team members from Realm took a look at the sample project and couldn't find anything wrong on the Realm side so far.

You can read the discussion from the issue

> github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5230

and download the [sample project](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/savori-6387d.appspot.com/o/Realm_Test_ProjectBB.zip?alt=media&token=24db5807-23e8-482c-bc14-39581d9b7658). It is already included both Realm frameworks and the dummy framework.
To see the error, just simply uncomment `import RealmSwift` at the top of the class file `TestClass.swift` which is under group path `Development Pods/RealmTest/RealmTest/Classes` within the `Pods` project in `RealmTest.xcworkspace`.

Am I doing a weird thing here including frameworks into a pod project to speed up build time? I couldn't find much of the related content on the Internet?

Thank you for your time!!

#### Xcode Version

8.3.2

#### Swift Version

3.1

#### Podspec

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'RealmTest'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'A short description of RealmTest.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/ivsall2012/RealmTest'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'ivsall2012' => 'ivsall2012@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/ivsall2012/RealmTest.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.source_files = 'RealmTest/Classes/**/*'
s.vendored_frameworks = 'RealmTest/DummyFramework.framework','RealmTest/Realm.framework', 'RealmTest/RealmSwift.framework'
end
```

#### Podfile

```
use_frameworks!

target 'RealmTest_Example' do
  pod 'RealmTest', :path => '../'

  target 'RealmTest_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths


  end
end
```

### Project that demonstrates the issue

[The sample project(32.96 MB)]

> (https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/savori-6387d.appspot.com/o/Realm_Test_ProjectBB.zip?alt=media&token=24db5807-23e8-482c-bc14-39581d9b7658)

Comment: Hi! I'm experiencing the same problem with a fat framework I'm working on. The host application fails linking Realm libraries, although I found a workaround: when I add the RealmSwift pod to the host application's Podfile, compilation ends successfully. 
Have you found any other neater way to solve this problem?